# How create a script for Google Docs with some Docs specific paragraphs configs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, paragraph

I'm trying to create a script for Google Docs with some specific paragraphs configs. Docs only have a few number of paragraphs styles (Title, Headings, etc.).

**I need a script with this configs:**

- 4 cm indentation;
- Arial, font size 10;
- Line spacing should be simple;
- A space of 1.5 must be left between the rest of the text and the citation;
- Justified text.

I've alredy found a good script on the internet but I have no idea how to modify this with the configs that I mentioned before (yes, I'm a newbie).

**Heres the code:**

```
// is called by google docs when a document is open
// adds a menu with a menu item that applies a style to the currently selected text
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Extras')
  .addItem('Apply code style', 'applyCodeStyle')
  .addToUi();
}
 
// definition of a style to be applied
var style = {
  bold: false,
  backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
  fontFamily: DocumentApp.FontFamily.CONSOLAS
};
 
// helper function that strips the selected element and passes it to a handler
function withElement(processPartial, processFull) {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if (element.getElement().editAsText) {
        var text = element.getElement();
        if (element.isPartial()) {
          var from = element.getStartOffset();
          var to = element.getEndOffsetInclusive();
          return processPartial(element, text, from, to);
        } else {
          return processFull(element, text);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
 
// called in response to the click on a menu item
function applyCodeStyle() {
  return withElement(
    applyPartialStyle.bind(this, style),
    applyFullStyle.bind(this, style)
  );
}
 
// applies the style to a selected text range
function applyPartialStyle(style, element, text, from, to) {
  text.setFontFamily(from, to, style.fontFamily);
  text.setBackgroundColor(from, to, style.backgroundColor);
  text.setBold(from, to, style.bold);
}
 
// applies the style if the entire element is selected
function applyFullStyle(style, element, text) {
  text.setFontFamily(style.fontFamily);
  text.setBackgroundColor(style.backgroundColor);
  text.setBold(style.bold); 
}
```

Tried to serch on the internet and ChatGPT, but no sucess.

**It's for a academic work. Please, guys, help!**

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result from `I need a script with this configs: 4 cm indentation;Arial, font size 10;Line spacing should be simple;A space of 1.5 must be left between the rest of the text and the citation;Justified text.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Just to clarify... "Docs only have a few number of paragraphs styles (Title, Headings, etc.)." Thhere are 6 Headings styles: [The headings actually go up to six, I believe, but you won't see more until you use heading 3.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/29527841?hl=en&msgid=29529554)

Comment: Code source appears to be [https://gist.github.com/fatso83](https://gist.github.com/fatso83/ffb7871c537e04d9ce95f66fccc30495). Last update Dec 2020

Comment: Mosna, this is not a trivial exercise and you acknowledge that you are a newbie so presumably your understanding of scripting is basic. Please clarify ASAP whether you have the scope to adapt one of the existing six Paragraph "Heading" styles to create your configuration.

Comment: Hello, guys (@Tanaike and @Tedinoz). Thanks for your comments. I wanna create a specific paragraph style for citations with this config: "4 cm indentation; Arial, font size 10; Line spacing should be simple; A space of 1.5 must be left between the rest of the text and the citation; Justified text". I've found the code script that I mentioned on the question because it works, but I have to adapt it to the paragraphs configs that I need. That's the point, guys: I have no idea how to adapt this. Some tips? Thanks all!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: In fact, I wanna create a new paragraph style (not "Headings" and "Titles") for my academic citations (that's the reason of some specifics configs, as font size, font type, etc.). Microsoft Word offers a "Citation" paragraph button, but Docs no.

Comment: @Tanaike, my english is not the best too, my friend! No need to worry about it. Your kindness is much appreciated! Thanks!